# Coloring faces for Sketchfab model

Tags: modeling, color

I am working on a few models which are going to be soon available for viewers via Sketchfab. Using guidelines from this forum I made a base for them through extruding the edges. 
Now I need to assign color to each extruded face. Unfortunately, faces inherited color from the edge and this is how they look now:

[image]

At first - I've selected all faces, changed to edit mode, and in material section added new material, set color and clicked <kbd>Assign</kbd>. This is, however, not reflected in the model in object mode or exported mesh.

What did I possibly do wrong? What should I do to be able to see all those modifications in mesh colored in Blender and reviewed later i.e. in MeshLab?

Comment: Possibly doubles in your model? Go to Edit Mode, select everything, hit "W" - "Remove Doubles". On second thought, why not separating those faces into a separate mesh?

Comment: You need to bake the material color to a texture...the problem is that the UVs are unwrapped onto the exact same pixel for the bottom and top of the extrusion.

Comment: would be a solution to assign a color to the edges before extrusion? Maybe in this way faces would receive color prior to further modifications?